# How does an Intelligence penalty affect skill points when character-building/leveling-up?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, pathfinder-1e

In character-building/leveling-up, you take your class's skill points and add your Int bonus.  So a Fighter gets 2 Plus their Int bonus.  Say my fighter is really smart(16) he'll get 2+3 (int bonus) or 5 points per level.

But what if my fighter is dumber than a sack hammers?  Let's say int 4.  He levels up and gets 2+int mod.  Int 4 carries a -3.  So it's 2+(-3) which equals -1.  How does a dumb fighter level up any of their skills if they have negative skill points?

Or is the int bonus only added if it's positive?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Skill points can never go below 1 Per level. From the Pathfinder SRD:

http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/ability-scores#TOC-Intelligence-Int-

- The number of skill points gained each level, though your character always gets at least 1 skill point per level.

Edit: I should note that there is also a difference between Ability **bonus** and ability **modifier**. Bonus only applies when the attribute is positive, modifier applies regardless. Skill points apply the modifier, per the SRD.

Comment: Also, if I'm not mistaken, you apply favored class and human bonuses after you've calculated the per-level for your class, in case that is pertinent.